# Json nested encryption value - Python

Tags: python, hashlib

I have a json output file and I am trying to encrypt a value of key(name) in it using sha256 encryption method. Have two occurence of name in a list of dict but everytime when I write, the changes reflecting once. Can anybody tell me where I am missing?

```
Json structure:
Output.json
{
    "site": [
        {
            "name": "google", 
            "description": "Hi I am google"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "microsoft", 
            "description": "Hi, I am microsoft"
        }
    ],
    "veg": [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "slot": null
        },
        {
            "status": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code:

```
import hashlib
import json

class test():
    def __init__(self):
    
    def encrypt(self):
        with open("Output.json", "r+") as json_file:
            res = json.load(json_file)
            for i in res['site']:
                for key,val in i.iteritems():
                    if 'name' in key:
                        hs = hashlib.sha256(val.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
                        res['site'][0]['name'] = hs
                        json_file.seek(0)
                        json_file.write(json.dumps(res,indent=4))
                        json_file.truncate()
```

Current Output.json

```
{
    "site": [
        {
            "name": "bbdefa2950f49882f295b1285d4fa9dec45fc4144bfb07ee6acc68762d12c2e3", 
            "description": "Hi I am google"
        }, 
        {
            "name": "microsoft", 
            "description": "Hi, I am microsoft"
        }
    ],
    "veg": [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "slot": null
        },
        {
            "status": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I'm having some issues reproducing. Are you reading or writing to the file? You didn't import json. You don't call the function. But I think you just have a problem with iterating through res. You should debug that. Search for "flattening" for some example code.

Comment: Hi @Kenny Ostrom, yah edited the code by importing json. I am trying to read that file and modify the name value by encrypting it and write back to the same json file. Iteration is working fine I think but while writing data somewhere its missing, because if i print res value its giving me two encryption values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in this line:

```
res['site'][0]['name'] = hs
```

you are always changing the `name` field of the first map in the `site` list.  I think you want this to be:

```
i['name'] = hs
```

so that you are updating the map you are currently working on (pointed to by `i`).

Instead of iterating over each item in the dictionary, you could make use of the fact that dictionaries are made for looking up values by key, and do this:

```
if 'name' in i:
    val = i['name']
    hs = hashlib.sha256(val.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    i['name'] = hs
    json_file.seek(0)
    json_file.write(json.dumps(res, indent=4))
    json_file.truncate()
```

instead of this:

```
for key,val in i.iteritems():
    if 'name' in key:
        ...
```

Also, `iteritems()` should be `items()`, and `if 'name' in key` should be `if key == 'name'`, as `key` is a string.  As it is, you'd be matching any entry with a key name containing the substring 'name'.

UPDATE:  I noticed that you are writing the entire file multiple times, once for each `name` entry that you encrypt.  Even without this I would recommend that you open the file twice...once for reading and once for writing.  This is preferred over opening a file for both reading and writing, and having to seek and truncate.  So, here are all of my suggested changes, along with a few other tweaks, in a full version of your code:

```
import hashlib
import json

class Test:

    def encrypt(self, infile, outfile=None):
        if outfile is None:
            outfile = infile
        with open(infile) as json_file:
            res = json.load(json_file)
        for i in res['site']:
            if 'name' in i:
                i['name'] = hashlib.sha256(i['name'].encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
        with open(outfile, "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(res, json_file, indent=4)

Test().encrypt("/tmp/input.json", "/tmp/output.json")

# Test().encrypt("/tmp/Output.json")  # <- this form will read and write to the same file
```

Resulting file contents:

```
{
    "site": [
        {
            "name": "bbdefa2950f49882f295b1285d4fa9dec45fc4144bfb07ee6acc68762d12c2e3",
            "description": "Hi I am google"
        },
        {
            "name": "9fbf261b62c1d7c00db73afb81dd97fdf20b3442e36e338cb9359b856a03bdc8",
            "description": "Hi, I am microsoft"
        }
    ],
    "veg": [
        {
            "status": "ok",
            "slot": null
        },
        {
            "status": "ok"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help.  Please check out my updated answer.  I had a few other suggestions to make, so I posted a full version of your code with all of my suggestions.